# Is it possible to identity notification details (or notification id) inside boardcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have multiple notifications send by different receivers(vendors). I implement a reply action button to reply to messages. Currently, I store notification details locally(shared preferences). Now, the reply action button working for single receiver notifications. Is it possible to identity notification details(or notification id) inside boardcastReceiver?

Is it possible to get from here?

```
  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val remoteInput: Bundle? = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent)
            val contentString = remoteInput.getCharSequence("NotificationReply").toString()
```

**Full Code**

**MessagingService**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                sendNotification(NotificationModel.from(remoteMessage.data))
        }
    }


    private fun sendNotification(notificationModel: NotificationModel) {
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

            val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("yellochatspfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString("message_data", notificationModel.messageData)
            editor.apply()
            editor.commit()

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_APPROVE,
                    Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
                            .putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_INTENT_APPROVE, MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_APPROVE),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yc_logo)
                .setContentTitle(notificationModel.title)
                .setContentText(notificationModel.body)
                .setGroup(notificationModel.groupKey)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.yc_logo))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setPriority(2)
                .setPriority(1)
                .setDefaults(2)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


            val replyLabel = "Enter your reply here"
            val remoteInput: RemoteInput = RemoteInput.Builder(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_REPLY)
                    .setLabel(replyLabel)
                    .build()
            val action: NotificationCompat.Action =
                    NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon,
                            "Reply", pendingIntent)
                            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                            .build()

            notificationBuilder.addAction(action)

        var notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.cancel(MainActivity.TAG_VALIDATION, 1)
        MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID = r.nextInt()
        notificationManager.notify(MainActivity.TAG_NORMAL, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    val db = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {

        val remoteInput: Bundle? = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent)
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            val contentString = remoteInput.getCharSequence("NotificationReply").toString()
            val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("yellochatspfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val messageData = sharedPreferences.getString("message_data", "")

            if (messageData != null && messageData != "") {
               // some logics to send message
                }else{
                    notificationProcess(sharedPreferences, false, context)
                }
            }else{
                notificationProcess(sharedPreferences, false, context)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun notificationProcess(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, isSuccess: Boolean, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `putExtra` to share data with `broadcastReceiver`

**MessagingService**

```
 val i = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
            i.putExtra("MESSAGE_DATA", notificationModel.messageData)
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_APPROVE,
                    i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
 val messageData = intent?.getStringExtra("MESSAGE_DATA")
 println("messageData is : $messageData")
```